# Can we do compound attribute filtring in REST?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

This is my JSON Data Model:

```
{
    "id": "1376109454",
    "type": "equipment",
    "name": "FAN",
    "manufacturerDetail": {
        "name": "PSPO",
        "date": {
            "day": "12",
            "month": "January",
            "year": "2013",
        }
    },
    "partNumber": "123507LD",
    "serviceState": "InService",
    "description": "Fan Front High Flow Cooling",
    "href": "http://<Server Name>:9010/api/house/equipment/-251116334"
  }
```

does REST allows us to do filtering on **manufacturerDetail.date.month** attribute using URL?

> http://Server_Name:9010/api/house/equipment?manufacturerDetail.date.month=January

Comment: Do you mean you want the above URL to return 'January'?

Comment: I mean if someone hit this URL server should return all  equipments which have **manufacturerDetail.date.month=January**

Comment: Are you asking if Jersey has already a built in mechanism to automatically do this for you? I believe theres nothing in the definition of a RESTful API that should prevent you from implementing a feature like this.

Comment: @tousdan Yes I have doubt whether Jesrsey provide such feature or not and if not what are the available approaches and how such feature being used in industry.